# Do not show images when an Angular app deployed to Github pages

Tags: angular, github-pages

```html
<div class="container">
    <img class="img" src="../../../assets/green-tea.png" alt="plant">
</div>
```

In my case when I run Angular app in localhost with using above code it works fine. But when I build and deploy it to Github pages image does not load.

But when changed the path for image to,

```html
<div class="container">
    <img class="img" src="./assets/green-tea.png" alt="plant">
</div>
```

like this it works in Github pages. But now it won't in localhost.

Is there a way to change `../../../assets/green-tea.png` path to `./assets/green-tea.png` automatically when building the app using `ng build --prod`

Comment: In one deployment `assets` is in the folder defined as site root and in other it is three folders down.

Comment: Are you using server when running locally ? Mostly for github I guess it is a static web page

Comment: @SantoshBalaji I use `ng serve` to run the app locally

Comment: @TheHeadRush is there a way to change `../../../assets/green-tea.png` path to `./assets/green-tea.png` automatically when building the app using `ng build --prod`